# How to prevent child's content from stretching parent's width

Tags: css, reactjs, flexbox

I have a component (`Container`) that contains an icon (marked with an `X` below), a title and a child component (`Message`) that contains a long message. I would like `Container's` width to wrap around the icon and the title so both are on one line as much as window's width allows for it.

Message component has a button that toggles display of a long text. This text should not stretch the parent `Container` and it should be aligned with title's width. The message content can be broken and wrapped at any point:

[image: text toggle off]

[image: text toggle on]

I used a `flex-grow: 1; width: 0;` style on a dummy `div` in `Message` as suggested 
[here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/9769587/set-div-to-have-its-siblings-width) to prevent it from growing. This works well on all browsers except for MS Edge, where the message content stretches the parent:

[image: edge]

How can I fix this issue on MS Edge?
Is there alternative way using only CSS that I can prevent the message content from stretching its parent?

**Style.css:**

```
.box {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

.message {
  display: flex;
}

.message > div {
  flex-grow: 1;
  width: 0;
  word-break: break-all;
}
```

**Container.jsx:**

```
export const Container = () => {
  return (
    <div className='box'>
      <div className='container'>
        <div className='icon'>
          X
        </div>
        <div className='content'>
          <div className='title'>
            Some title
          </div>
          <Message>
            Long message that should not make parent wider
          </Message>
        </div>
      </div>
    </div>
  );
}
```

**Message.jsx:**

```
export const Message = ({children}) => {
  const [isExpanded, setExpanded] = React.useState(false);

  const handleClick = () => setExpanded(!isExpanded);

  return (
    <div>
      <div>
        <button onClick={handleClick}>Click</button>
      </div>
      {isExpanded &&
        <div className='message'>
          <div>{children}</div>
        </div>
      }
    </div>
  );
}
```

Comment: Try to set max width for parent

Answer (score 41, accepted):

Try `width:0;min-width:100%;` on the message container:

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

message {
  display:block;
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='icon'>
      X
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='title'>
        Some title
      </div>
      <message>
        <div>Long message that should not make parent wider</div>
      </message>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Or to the div inside the message:

```css
.box {
  display: table;
  margin: auto;
  border: 1px solid black;
}

.container {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
}

.icon {
  margin-right: 10px;
}

message {
  display:block;
}
message  > div {
  width:0;
  min-width:100%;
}
```

```html
<div class='box'>
  <div class='container'>
    <div class='icon'>
      X
    </div>
    <div class='content'>
      <div class='title'>
        Some title
      </div>
      <message>
        <div>Long message that should not make parent wider</div>
      </message>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Comment: I spent several hours trying to get a pre-tag to behave, with box-sizing, display alternatives, widths etc. I have no clue why this works, but it did the trick. My issue was that the pre-tag leaked its width to the parent component as long as I had dynamic width 100% to be contained in its parent and so forth.

Comment: you saved a lot o time trying to fix my component

Comment: Could anyone explain why this works?

Comment: @WesternCreamCheese check the duplicate question

Comment: don't know why it works but it does. I don't know why this has to be hard.
Something like:
growth-due-to-children: 0%;
growth-due-to-parent: 100%;
would make a lot of sense.