# How do I use relative positioning inside a button?

Tags: css

I have a simple [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/9u4nw1fv/15/) I am basically trying to overlay one div over another. I can do this easily in a traditional div (see purple) but when I try the same thing with a button it doesn't work.

```
<button>
  <div class="background">&nbsp;</div>
  <div class="label">This is the label</div>
</button>

.background{
  background-color: green;
  height: 100%;
}
.label{
  position: relative;
  top: -100%;
}
```

How do I position a div relatively inside a button?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You could use `position: absolute;` on the child `.label` and `position: relative;` on the parent `button`.

Like this:

```
button {
  position: relative;
}

.label{
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
}
```

Comment: I still have the question of absolute positioning and mobile though. I will try it out but I remember absolute positioning having issues in older browsers.

Comment: It doesn't look that bad - https://caniuse.com/#search=position%3A%20absolute

Comment: It has been a while but I will see if it works like I need to on the browsers I use (especially Safari because that seems to lag).

Comment: So If you can fix this I will give you the check back (https://jsfiddle.net/9u4nw1fv/19/) notice it doesn't maintain a width unless declared.

Comment: The reason it doesn't maintain a width is that the background doesn't adjust it's width after the sibling

Comment: I got it to work by switching and fiddling with the z-index. The problem is the top element sets the size for the whole button. The issue I have here is this makes me need a z-index on all items I expect to show up. I tried just putting it on the label but it doesn't work https://jsfiddle.net/9u4nw1fv/30/

Comment: @Jackie See this: https://stackoverflow.com/a/48226415/9572013. I don't know if it works with buttons, but it makes an element the size of it's sibling

Answer (score 0):

You can do it like this:

```
button{
    position: relative; /* will make all absolute elements inside it relative to itself */
}
.label{
    position: absolute;
    top: -100%;
}
```

Comment: Does this work even if it is in the middle of the screen?

Comment: Also I used to have trouble with absolute positioning on mobile browsers is that resolved?

Comment: I tried here and it did not work https://jsfiddle.net/9u4nw1fv/16/